# Divide array contents on multiple lines MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I almost managed to split the different arrays and to prepare them in the table in the MySQL database, I'll explain the situation:

On the main page, the user has the ability to add and remove rows in a table. The table for each line carries with it these inputs:

```
input1.name = "product[]";

input2.name = "seller[]";

input3.name = "description[]";

input4.name = "quantity[]";

input5.name = "priece[]";
```

so if the user inserts two rows in each array will be included descriptions of two products, for example:

product: "PS3", "PS4";

seller: "AMAZON", "SONY";

description: "100Gb", "200Gb";

quantity: "1", "2";

price: "100", "200";

This is the layout table:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/ux0su8ssdixfmgc/Cattura2.JPG

The problem arises. I capture the data entered via a post, but I can't distribute these data on several lines. I want you to PS3 both into the first row of MySQL table, and PS4 in the second row of the table. Until now arrays are instantiated only on the first line, in this way, however, there is only one product. It is therefore necessary to prepare each box in the appropriate row of the array. I do not know if I was clear, but I would like to achieve something like this:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/d6f6ahy834jv0p2/Cattura.JPG

Obviously, the data in table I've entered manually and not through code. Was it right for you to understand.
This is the code that I currently use to send multiple arrays on different lines, but it doesn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['sending']))
    {
        if($_POST['sending'] == "save")
        {
            $row_data = array();
            foreach($_POST['sending'] as $key => $value) 
            { 
                $product=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['product'][$row]));
                $seller=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['seller'][$row]));
                $description=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['description'][$row]));
                $quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['quantity'][$row]));
                $priece=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['priece'][$row]));
                $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['user'][$row]));
                $row_data[] = "('$product', '$seller', '$description','$quantity', '$priece', '$user')";
            }
                if (!empty($row_data))
                {
                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO test(product,seller,description,quantity,priece,user) VALUES '.implode(',', $row_data);
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql );

                    if ($result)
                    echo 'ADD COMPLETE!: ' . mysqli_affected_rows($con);
                    else
                    echo 'ERROR' ;
                }           
        } // if ($_POST['sending'] == "save")
    } // if (isset($_POST['sending'])) 
}//close method
```

Comment: So, Serialisation, plus usual caveats about Php's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Is there anyone who can give me a working example?

Comment: What is `$row` variable?

Comment: Through it I think I may be able to access the corresponding line but I'm not sure. The code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood it well this is how it should work

```
if(isset($_POST['sending']))
{
    if($_POST['sending'] == "save")
    {
        $row_data = array();
        foreach($_POST['sending'] as $key => $value) 
        { 
            $product=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['product'][$row]));
            $seller=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['seller'][$row]));
            $description=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['description'][$row]));
            $quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['quantity'][$row]));
            $priece=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['priece'][$row]));
            $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['user'][$row]));
            array_push($row_data, "('$product', '$seller', '$description','$quantity', '$priece', '$user')");
        }

foreach($row_data as $value){
            if (!empty($value))
            {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO test(product,seller,description,quantity,priece,user) VALUES '.$value;
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql );

                if ($result)
                echo 'ADD COMPLETE!: ' . mysqli_affected_rows($con);
                else
                echo 'ERROR' ;
            }           
    } // if ($_POST['sending'] == "save")
  } // if (isset($_POST['sending'])) 
}//close method
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in: foreach($_POST['sending'] as $key => $value) 
why?

Comment: My bad, I have just saw it, $_POST['sending'] is not an array, thats why it gives warning. What you need to do is insted of foreach use for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST['product[]']);$i++) and insteda of $row use $i. Though you should test it

Comment: I fix the problem finally. However, thaks for support.